# Rails 5. Strong params require not used if one permit key is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 to create a JSON Api.

My controller uses strong parameters with one **require** attribute like this:

```
params.require(:require_attribute).permit(:permit_attribute1,:permit_attribute2)
```

Normally I have to send my JSON like this:

```
{
    "require_attribute":{
        "permit_attribute1": "data",
        "permit_attribute2": "data"
    }
}
```

And if the required attribute is missing,I have to get this message:

```
"ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: require_attribute"
```

My problem is, if I remove the required attribute from JSON and I have one `permit` attribute in common with strong params it does work.

The JSON I send :

```
{
    "permit_attribute1": "data",
}
```

When I get *params* in `log` I have:

> {"permit1"=>data, "controller"=>"mycontroller", "action"=>"create", **"require_attribute"=>{"permit1"=>1}**}

It seems Rails creates a hash with required key instead of raising an error.
But I want to force the required attribute when I receive a JSON.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What do you use to send that "simpler" json? Is  it angular/restangular, by any chance?

Comment: I use curl in console or Postman addon

Answer (score 4):

> The strong parameter API was designed with the most common use cases
>   in mind. It is not meant as a silver bullet to handle all your
>   whitelisting problems.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

> `require(key)`
>
> Ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns the
>   parameter at the given key, otherwise raises an
>   `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

As you can see from the above setting required parameters on a "flat" hash is not really what the strong parameters API is built for. Rather its built around the rails conventions where params are nested under a single key.

You could use ´.require´ to pull a single key at once but that would be rather clumsy.

Rather you can simulate what it does by raising an exception unless the key is present:

```
def something_params
  req = [:required_attribute1, :required_attribute2]
  req.each do |k|
    raise ActionController::ParameterMissing.new(k) unless params[k].present?
  end
  whitelisted = params.permit(:permit_attribute1, :permit_attribute2)
end
```

However a better method altogether may be to use model level validations - `ActionController::ParameterMissing` is supposed to indicate that the general formatting of the request is off - not that a required attribute is missing. For example for a JSONAPI.org formatted request you would do:

```
params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:email, :username)
```

Which ensures that the request follows the standard. However enforcing that a User cannot be created without an email is a model level concern.

Comment: All right, but why is `require` not raising an error when the required key isn't present ? This seems to be the expected behavior here.

Comment: No, not really. Consider that the parameters are written to the log before rails even matches the request to a route and instantiates the controller.  I'm not sure if the error is in how you are sending the request or some really strange issue where Rack or some middleware is coercing the request params.

Comment: Also `.require` does not actually modify `request.params`. It returns a copy. If you check the server log and the params look like that you have something fishy going on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default Rails in API mode wraps JSON request parameters into a hash guessing its name from controller class. You can read details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

If you don't need this functionality in your app just remove `:json` from `:format` array in `config\initializers\wrap_parameters.rb`. Or you can use fine-grained control at the controller level as described above.

This way you'll get an exception when the required key isn't present.